# Rails No route matches [POST] "/exercises/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My app features some admittedly-nested routes. Each workout `has_many` exercises, and each exercise `has_many` results.  In trying to create a new exercise, I'm getting an error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/exercises/new"
```

Here is the part on my `workouts#show` page where all the magic takes place:

```
<%= render 'exercises/form', exercise: Exercise.new, workout: @workout %>
```

Here is the `exercises/_form.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= form_for [workout, exercise] do |f| %>

...(form stuff)...

<div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Create Exercise", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>

<% end %>
```

Here is my `exercises#controller`:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:destroy, :create]

  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.new(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:post_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercise.find(params[:id])

    if comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
    params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :seconds, :weight, :reps)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my routes:

```
workout_exercise_reports POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports(.:format)     reports#create
 workout_exercise_report DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:exercise_id/reports/:id(.:format) reports#destroy
       workout_exercises GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#index
                         POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercises(.:format)                          exercises#create
    new_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/new(.:format)                      exercises#new
   edit_workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id/edit(.:format)                 exercises#edit
        workout_exercise GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/:id(.:format)                      exercises#destroy
                workouts GET    /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#index
                         POST   /workouts(.:format)                                                workouts#create
             new_workout GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                                            workouts#new
            edit_workout GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)                                       workouts#edit
                 workout GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#show
                         PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                         PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#update
                         DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                                            workouts#destroy
```

This comes from this `routes.rb` structure:

```
  resources :workouts do
     resources :exercises do
       resources :reports
     end
  end
```

I would welcome any wisdom anyone can shed on the situation, including how to fix the error (mainly) but also if there's a better way to structure my routes.

ADDITIONAL INFO

Here is my `workouts#controller`:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    workout = @workout
    exercise = workout.exercises.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the full trace for the error:

```
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What line does it show the error?

Comment: No line, it just shows my routes...

Comment: There is no routes `[POST] "/exercises/new"` in your app. You have as `[GET]` in your routes.

Comment: @GokulM After editing out the nesting resources (see above changes) and still getting the same error, I tried specifying the route to use with `<%= form_for [workout, exercise], url: exercises_path do |f| %>` and it didn't change the error message either.

Comment: Try this: `<%= render 'exercises/form', exercise: @workout.exercises.new, workout: @workout %>` with your old routes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work with the old nested routes or with the new unnested ones.  (Same error message.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exercises nested under your **workouts** resource.
Hence to create a new exercises, you need to specify the workout for which you are trying to create the exercise.

As shown in the routes, you need to hit 
`[POST] /workouts/:workout_id/exercises/new`
this route for creating exercises.
Instead of what is being shown in the error `[POST] "/exercises/new"`.

Your design of the routes implies and requires you to specify for each exercise which workout it belongs to. And each report has to specify which exercise and consequently which workout it belongs to.

You can change the design if your requirement is different.

Comment: I tried un-nesting them, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: You have defined `exercises/new` as GET